# The Manual Performance result and Jmeter result on server hosted in US Differ but the results of JMeter and manual performance match on local machine

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

We are working on an Open Finn application hosted on a US server.

1.While we run the application on our local machine and note the performance timings manually and JMeter they are almost identical

2.But when we run the application on US server the Manual performance timings and JMeter results vary with a very large margin.

How can we achieve to make the Manual and JMeter results identical on both Server and local machine.

I have applied all header and cache managers but it did not make much difference.

What i noticed was in HTTP requests the latency was zero on server but the manual results were still taking time and were similar to the local machine results but JMeter was not at all identical to when we ran JMeter on local machine.